# Greasemonkey-issued redirect only works if alert() is called after the redirection line

Tags: javascript, redirect, greasemonkey

I have a site at work that when not logged in, redirects to the wrong login page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <script type="application/javascript">
      window.location.href = '/access/login?return_to=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

The actual page is loaded with a 200 OK and no `Location:` header.

To remedy this, I composed a Greasemonkey script to run before pageload:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Fix buggy login redirect
// @namespace  apburk@example.com
// @description Fixes the buggy redirect that redirects to the wrong login page
// @include    https://internal.domain/*
// @version    1
// @grant      none
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==
window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {
if (document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].text.trim() === "window.location.href = '/access/login?return_to=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);") {

window.location.replace('https://example.com');
alert(" ");
}

}, true);
```

My script checks if the JavaScript to redirect to the wrong page is there, then sends me off to the correct login URL.

This script works fine -- if the `alert()` is there. Remove the `alert()` and the page redirects to the broken login page. However, when `alert()` *is* there, I never see the alert box, but *do* get redirected to the proper page.

I could leave the `alert()` in, as it doesn't ever seem to run, but I'd like to remove it and still have the page redirect to my desired page.

My questions regarding this issue:

- Why is this occurring? Is a timing issue involved?
- How can I make this work properly without a useless `alert()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code has some "race conditions".  With the `alert()` missing, the old JS still fires before the `location.replace();` finishes.
The alert takes time to fire. With it in place, the `location.replace` finishes before it can.

The correct thing is to stop the script and then fire the replace.  Do that with `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`. Something like so:

```
window.addEventListener ('beforescriptexecute', function (e) {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName ("script")[0].text.trim()
        === "window.location.href = '/access/login?return_to=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);"
    ) {
        e.stopPropagation ();
        e.preventDefault ();
        window.location.replace ('https://example.com');
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Ah!! That explains it; tried it and it works wonderfully. I didn't previously know about stopPropagation, nor preventDefault. Thank you for your time!